# Udacity - Flask Python

Tags: python, api, flask, python-unittest

I've been working on a Udacity course on unit testing flask application.

All the files needed are in this [Github link](https://github.com/udacity/nd0044-c2-API-Development-and-Documentation-exercises/tree/master/3_Testing_Review), and we will just focus on the "backend" directory.  This directory contains the flaskr directory and two files - one of which  is the `test_flaskr.py`, where there is this [test_delete_book](https://github.com/udacity/nd0044-c2-API-Development-and-Documentation-exercises/blob/master/3_Testing_Review/backend/test_flaskr.py#L82-L93) method that i am trying to fix.

The way this `test_delete_book` test method is coded currently it will only pass the FIRST test (and will fail in succeeding tests).  So what I am trying to do is to get the value of the 'id' key of the last Book entry, and pass it to the `delete book` API .  There is another [test_create_new_book](https://github.com/udacity/nd0044-c2-API-Development-and-Documentation-exercises/blob/master/3_Testing_Review/backend/test_flaskr.py#L64-L71) method in the same test file `test_flaskr.py` that ensures the Book table will never run out of data (thus the `test_delete_book` will never fail after my code change.

By the way, here is the [link](https://github.com/udacity/nd0044-c2-API-Development-and-Documentation-exercises/blob/master/3_Testing_Review/backend/models.py#L26-L32) to the Book table structure.

Here is my code for the test_delete_book (emphasis on just two lines - lines 03 and 04):

```
01    # Delete a different book in each attempt
02    def test_delete_book(self):
03        book = Book.query.order_by(Book.id.desc()).first()
04        book_id_to_delete = book.id
05        # res = self.client().delete('/books/<book_id_to_delete')
06        res = self.client().delete('/books/' + str(book_id_to_delete))
07        data = json.loads(res.data)
80
09        book = Book.query.filter(Book.id == book_id_to_delete).one_or_none()
10
11        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
12        self.assertEqual(data['success'], True)
13        self.assertEqual(data['deleted'], book_id_to_delete)
14        self.assertTrue(data['total_books'])
15        self.assertTrue(len(data['books']))
16        self.assertEqual(book, None)
```

On line 03 I coded the SQLAlchemy query to get the book.id value of the last Book table entry, and save off the last book id value in the `book_id_to_delete` variable.  BTW this test actually interfaces with a database (not mocked).  Before I run the test, I noted the "id" key of the last Book table entry.  When i ran the test, ***all tests passed***, but the last table entry was still in the table.  Also, I did not see a new record that's supposed to be created by the `test_create_new_book` method I mentioned earlier.

Here is where it gets weird (at least for me):

When I modified line #04 by replacing the "book.id" with the actual book id value of the last entry in the Book table THEN ran the tests, not only did the last entry gets DELETED from the Book table, but I can also see the new book table record that's created by the `test_create_new_book` method.

Any helpful input would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to debug the unit test, and i was able to see that a record is actually being deleted. My unit test includes a test case where a record is created, and my delete test case takes the LAST record (which was added by my "create test case") and successfully deleted it.

Python-wise, the following line

```
res = self.client().delete('/books/' + str(book_id_to_delete)
```

should be replaced with this:

```
res = self.client().delete('/books/{}'.format(str(book_id_to_delete)))
```